# PHP manipulating arrays without foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Would anyone happen to know if there is an even more efficient way or single function that will achieve the below without the need for a foreach loop? I understand that it will have practically no performance issue on the below however I'm always looking for new and hopefully more efficient ways to code.

*(Push first element value to key, push second element value to new key value, unset old data)*

Input

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [supplier_id] => 1
            [supplier_company] => Company Alpha
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [supplier_id] => 2
            [supplier_company] => Company Beta
        )

)
```

Function

```
foreach ($suppliers as $key => $value) {
      $new_array[$value['supplier_id']] = $value['supplier_company'];
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => Company Alpha
    [2] => Company Beta
)
```

Comment: since you are not using the `$key` value you can eliminate `$key =>` part of your loop

Comment: Also, use `foreach ($suppliers as &$value)` instead.  As said on another comment, this will speed up your code because you will be accessing to a pointer instead of making a copy of the data. After that, you can safely use `unset($suppliers)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) will do the trick:

```
$inp = array(
    array(
        'supplier_id' => 1,
        'supplier_company' => 'Company Alpha'
    ),array(
        'supplier_id' => 2
        'supplier_company' => 'Company Beta'
    )
);

$out = array_column($inp,'supplier_company','supplier_id');

var_dump($out);
/*
Array
(
    [1] => Company Alpha
    [2] => Company Beta
)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
$arr = array
    (
     0 => array
     (
      'supplier_id' => 3,
      'supplier_company' => 'Company Alpha'
      ),

     1 => array
     (
      'supplier_id' => 4,
      'supplier_company' => 'Company Beta'
      )

     );

     $names = array_map(function ($arg){return array($arg['supplier_id']=>$arg['supplier_company']);}, $arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_column` does exactly that, as others have mentioned.

Now, just for fun, you could try something creative like using `extract` within your foreach loop. Both your IDE and your teammates will squeak at you, through.

```
foreach($inp as $supplier) {
    extract($supplier);

    // magic variables!
    echo $supplier_id;
    echo $supplier_company;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I started typing my answer and went for testing, before reading other comments. I've removed the duplicated part. The rest of my answer is pretty original, though ;)

Comment: No arguments against that. Even though it is original, the requirement was to do not use `foreach`. You can use `foreach($inp as &$supplier)` as a speed improvement (since you will be using a pointer instead of copying the memory). I've upvoted it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `PHP5 >= 5.5.0`, you can try `array_column` as following :

```
$suppliers = array_column($suppliers, 'supplier_company','supplier_id');
print_r($suppliers);
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use the function [`each()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php), which is available since ever, with the constructor [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

Here is an example:

```
$a=array(
    array(
        'a'=>0,'b'=>5
    ),
    array(
        'a'=>'no','b'=>'yes'
    )
);

while(list(,$tmp) = each($a))$new_array[$tmp['a']] = $tmp['b'];

var_dump($new_array);
```

Should output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(5)
  ["no"]=>
  string(3) "yes"
}
```

Both methods exist since PHP4, so, you can use them forever.

If you want to squeeze a tiny bit more of performance, you can use pointers:

```
while(list(,$tmp) = each(&$a))$new_array[$tmp['a']] = &$tmp['b'];
```

It is safe to use `unset($a)` after!
This is faster because you are simply assigning a pointer to a memory address, instead of providing a new copy of the array.